# scp from local computer to EC2 instance (with WSL) - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following this [guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/WSL.html) and try to copy a simple code from local directory into EC2 instance.

Up to and incl. section **Connect to your Linux instance using WSL**, everything works as in the AWS guidance. But when I try to copy a python file from local computer into the EC2 instance using the code below,

```
sudo mkdir WSL-path
cd WSL-path
sudo cp /mnt/c/.../test-pair2.pem test-pair2.pem
sudo cp /mnt/c/.../hello_world.py hello_world.py
sudo chmod -R 400 test-pair2.pem
scp -i test-pair2.pem hello_world.py ec2-user@ec2-18-184-76-175.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

I cannot connect to the instance and get the following:

```
Load key "test-pair2.pem": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

The key in the local instance can be only read by the user, with the default I could not even connect to EC2. But otherwise I think I am following the AWS manual. Would much appreciate explanation what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you SSH in with the key?

Comment: Yes, "sudo ssh -i test-pair2.pem ec2-user@[DNS]" works.

Comment: What's the output of ssh -i key user@host -vv

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission denied check the following factors:

- Is the key you're using using permissions `400`. To check run ls -lah `test-pair2.pem`. If not fix it by using `chmod 400`.
- Is the owner of the file you, if not run `chown $USERNAME test-pair2.pem`.

As it works with sudo we know that the host is the issue, not the target.

Answer (score -1):

So problem solved - silly mistake - adding SUDO works:

```
sudo scp -i test-pair2.pem hello_world.py ec2-user@ec2-18-184-76-175.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

Comment: I do this every day and sudo is not necessary in wsl